# npm ERR! Missing script: "build"

Tags: reactjs, npm

I am  trying to deploy a react project but  did not use create-react-app to start the project i used a site called createapp.dev so i don't know if that is the issue. i included my package.json  and an image of the error is as follows [image: "Error"]

```json
    "scripts": {
    "predeploy": "npm run build",
    "deploy": "gh-pages -d build",
    "clean": "rm dist/bundle.js",
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build-prod": "parcel build src/index.html"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "node-sass": "^7.0.1",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.3.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.18.5",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.18.2",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.17.12",
    "gh-pages": "^4.0.0",
    "parcel-bundler": "^1.12.5",
    "prettier": "^2.7.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: Where did those scripts come from? Unfortunately if that `build` script is missing, it may be a bug with the site you used.

Comment: [Createapp.dev](https://createapp.dev/)

Answer (score 2):

You don't have a script called "build" in your package.json. Try with "build-prod" instead!

Comment: Better than my answer, and probably correct. It's almost certainly a bug in the site OP used to generate the `package.json`.

Comment: it builds with "build-prod"  but when i try to deploy the error still comes up

Comment: It still pops up because predeploy is calling the script called build, try changing "npm run build" to "npm run build-prod" in predeploy and see if it works

Answer (score 1):

`npm run build` means to run the script called `build` from that list you provided. Your list doesn't have a script called `build`, so it fails.

Comment: I'm sorry the issue is with this createapp.dev you use "npm run build-prod" instead of "npm run build"  but after it builds and i try to deploy it the error still comes up

Comment: Why are you using that site over something like `create-react-app`? It seems to not be worth the headaches. It does look pretty cool though.

Comment: i'm new to react so i decided to try it out . but when i used create-react-app after all the headaches and copied the codes there a bunch of errors came up

Answer (score 0):

Your script is not having `build` command specified that's the reason `npm run build` will fail.

Following are the observation from your `package.json` scripts:

```js
"scripts": {
    "predeploy": "npm run build", // will run the code before deploy
    "deploy": "gh-pages -d build", // gh-pages => github pages hence this is for github deployment
    "clean": "rm dist/bundle.js", // rm to remove the bundle.js
    "start": "react-scripts start", // to start the react-app
    "build-prod": "parcel build src/index.html" // to make build using parcel module bundler
  }
```

Typically `create-react-app` uses [Webpack](https://webpack.js.org/) as it's module bundler and here it's using [Parcel](https://parceljs.org/). Depending on bundler there are different functionality and syntax as well as approach for the code from start to end.

As defined in your `package.json` instead of `npm run build` try `npm run build-prod` this will create build with parcel for `src/index.html` as root.

Generally `npm run build` will run the following `react-scripts build` you can try adding following into the `scripts` but I doubt it will work as build need to be created based on the module bundler used. You can give it a shot by adding following into scripts.

```json
"build": "react-scripts build",
```

If it makes proper build with proper module bundler rules then it will run or else it will keep throwing errors.